# How is the expression "$a\equiv b \mod n$" pronounced?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic

How is this expression pronounced ?

> $$a\equiv b \mod n$$

For example:

> $$24\equiv 4\mod 5$$

What is the "meaning" of  **mod**? This word is a shortened version of which word?
And what is the meaning of "**modular**"?

Comment: The internet is a great source of information, just search for "modular arithmetic".  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) is a good place to start.

Comment: I (and my proffessors) pronounce it: $a$ is congruent to $b$ modulo $n$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_(jargon)

Comment: mod derives form "modulus or "moduli", look here for any information https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Comment: The symbol $\mod{}$ stands for the word it should be pronounced as: "modulo", as in "$a$ is congruent to $b$ modulo $n$". Depending on your proficiency with the formal approach, you may either consider the entire expression $$a\equiv b\pmod n$$ as synonymous with "there is an integer $k\in\Bbb Z$ such that $a-b=kn$", or as being an identity of classes in the quotient ring $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Much obliged!..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say something like "$a$ is equivalent [or congruent] to $b$ mod $n$"—"mod" here being pronounced to rhyme with "rod" or "pod" etc.  Some people say "equal" instead of "equivalent"; as long as the "mod $n$" part is there, it doesn't much matter.

---

It just now occurred to me that you also asked what the term "modulus" or "modulo" means.  Practically, if we say that

$$
a \equiv b \bmod n
$$

we mean that $a$ and $b$ both leave the same remainder when divided by $n$; that is, there exist integer values $p$, $q$, and $r$ such that

$$
a = pn + r
$$
$$
b = qn + r
$$
$$
0 \leq r < n
$$

It's called "modular" arithmetic from Latin *modulus* "little measure"; the implication is that the modulus $n$ is what you use to measure out the quantities $a$ and $b$.  What's left (if anything) is the same in either case.

Answer (score 1):

$a$ is congruent to $b$ modulo $n$.

It means that they have the same remainder when you divide them by $n$, or shortly:

$$n\ \text{ divides }\ b-a$$

The "meaning", roughly, is that $a$ and $b$ become "equivalent" if you consider $n$ to be "equivalent" to $0$.

Just like $90$ and $-270$ are equivalent if you consider $360$ to be the same as $0$... if that rings a bell.

Answer (score 1):

It is short for "modulo", and that's how it is pronounced, "$24$ equals $4$ modulo $5$". Colloquially, it means that 4 is the reminder of the división $24/4$. More exactly, that $4$ is the standard representative of the equivalence class of $24$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/5$.

Comment: This interpretation holds only when the RHS is less than the modulus though, I don't think that the OP wants to jump to that part before learning the basics.